# NetworkImage(url) not working | Invalid image data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to show profil image using `NetwokImage`. I have checked the link in browser and it's work. I try to `log` the link in terminal and it work. But the photo still not showing.

**here is the code**

```
Widget header() {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: defaultMargin,
          left: defaultMargin,
          right: defaultMargin,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Hello, ${user.name}!",
                    style: primaryTextStyle.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 24, fontWeight: semiBold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 2,
                  ),
                  Text("@${user.username}",
                      style: subtitleTextStyle.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 16, fontWeight: regular))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 54,
              width: 54,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(user.profilePhotoUrl),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

**this is the log**

```
[log] https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=s&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF
```

**This is the error message**

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:6408:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:6265:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodecFromBuffer (dart:ui/painting.dart:2150:60)
#3      PaintingBinding.instantiateImageCodecFromBuffer (package:flutter/src/painting/binding.dart:153:15)
#4      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:135:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=s&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=s&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with overall setup is that, I checked the output of ui-avatars.com API and it returns an SVG, and not a jpg or png.

Flutter Images do not support SVG yet out of the box, you need to use a library [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) to display SVGs.

```dart
final Widget networkSvg = SvgPicture.network(
  'https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=s&color=7F9CF5&background=EBF4FF',
  semanticsLabel: 'A shark?!',
  placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
);
```

I have taken this example from the documentation of the library.

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer if that works for you.